# Installing postgresql on CentOS 5.5 postgresql-setup initdb command not found error

Tags: postgresql, centos, odoo-9

I was following these steps to install postgresql and then odoo v9 :

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html

Basically it follows these steps outlined here:

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/issue-while-installing-following-the-instructions-for-packaged-installers-rpm-93756

I get exactly the same situation.  The first steps go through without issue but then the postgresql-setup initdb command cannot be found.

I have root access to the server and I know it's running centOS5.5.  How can I troubleshoot this?  I believe I installed the 9.4 version but when I do psql -V I get the server has v8.3.

I ran some commands on the server and here are the results:

postgresql-setup initdb
command cannot be found

postgres
root execution is not permitted, server must be restarted as underprivileged id...

initdb
no data directory specified, you must identify dir where datase system will reside

locate postgresql
i get an .rb, .xml and .yml files

locate psql
/usr/lib64 - a few libodbcpsql.so files

pqsl -V
8.1.23

I get command not found for all other commands in the list of commands to install odoo up until sudo yum config manager --add-repo etc...

sudo su postgres -c "psql -c 'show data_directory'"
could not change directory to 'the directory im currently in on my server'

[image: ssh responses]